# How do I make a textfield editable for 10 seconds on the click of a button?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

Using JavaFX, on the click of a button I want to do this:

```
spinBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    field.setDisable(false);
    //Delay for 10 seconds
    field.setDisable(true);         
    }
});
```

I quickly realized that sleeping wouldn't work as it freezes the GUI completely. I've also tried sleeping threads to get a timer but that still freezes the GUI if input where I want the delay. (Example below)

```
spinBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    ExampleTimerThread exampleSleepyThread = new ExampleTimerThread();//this extends Thread
    exampleSleepyThread.start(); 
//thread sleeps for 10 secs & sets public static boolean finished = true; after sleep 
    while(finished == true){
        field.setDisable(false);
        }           
    }
});
```

What could I do to prevent this code from freezing the GUI up?
I know in Swing, there is a timer. Is there something similar in JavaFX?

Comment: You can try `Platform.runLater` from the thread after 10 seconds and call a function in the main thread that now disables the text field.

Comment: I think that could work fine, but from what I tried it was giving me problems and I figured there had to be a different, simpler way(in my opinion) like MBec's answer.

Comment: I agree, MBec's answer seems much better suited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `PauseTransition` to delay events:

```
spinBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
    field.setDisabled(false);
    PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(10));
    pt.setOnFinished(ev -> {
        field.setDisabled(true);
    });
    pt.play();
});
```

Comment: I do want to add, I believe setDisable is the correct syntax for JavaFX. It gave me an error when I tried to use setDisabled. I tried to edit it but there were too few characters changed.

Comment: What type of error did you get? Or better ask another question.

Comment: The error said "The method setDisabled(boolean) from the type Node is not visible". I changed it all to setDisable and it worked.

Comment: I apologize, I realize it was incorrect in my original question. I fixed it.